# freebsd add custom syscall by compiling the kernel?

Tags: freebsd

for school work I have to add custom helloworld syscall to freebsd. I used following link as my guide: http://members.tripod.com/s_mathur/bsdhowto.html
OK!
In step two I got problem: root has not permission to run it so I used: "make sysent" instead. seems ok.
Step 4 says: 4. Modify the Makefile to include sys_hello.c,etc and recompile the kernel.!!!
Which makefile? and how to compile it and how call syscall hello?
tnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sys_hello.c contains your syscall implementation - and it's in sys/kern/sys_hello.c - then add this file to conf/files.  Search for eg. "kern_fork.c" there and add sys_hello.c in a similar way.  Afterwards, rebuild and reinstall kernel and world (make buildkernel buildworld installkernel installworld); world rebuild is neccessary to get the userspace part into libc.so.  As for calling - well, call it like you would call another syscall.  You will need to add the syscall declaration somewhere.

Comment: yes, sys_hello.c is in sys/kern. but there is no .c file in sys/conf so is it the place. there is no sys_hello.h to include in kern_fork.c. what should I do?

Comment: The sys/conf/files - literally, "files", no extension - contains list of kernel source files to use (apart from kernel modules, which are built based on Makefiles in sys/modules/).  As for sys_hello.h - yeah, I don't know where this file could come from; just don't include it?