# Add new system call at FreeBSD 10.1

Tags: unix, kernel, system-calls, freebsd

I wanna add new system call at FreeBSD. My system call code is:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/systm.h>
#include <sys/kernel.h>
#include <sys/proc.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <sys/sysproto.h>

int Sum(int a, int b);

int
Sum(a,b)
{
   int c;
   c = a + b;
   return (0);
}
```

But when I rebuild the kernel, I have an error:

[image]

What's wrong? Can you help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is my code true or not?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the code and error as plain text rather than including screenshots?

Comment: @ajshort Yeah, I change it :)

Comment: No need to ping other users (with `Can you help me?`). Also, referring with `@` works only for users in the current discussion.

Comment: This seems to be a common question; eg see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755770/freebsd-add-custom-syscall-by-compiling-the-kernel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I did it with my example system call of setkey which takes two unsigned ints.
I added my system call to the end /kern/syscalls.master

```
546 AUE_NULL    STD { int setkey(unsigned int k0, unsigned int k1);}
```

Then I did

```
cd /usr/src
sudo make -C /sys/kern/ sysent
```

Next, I added the file to /sys/conf/files

```
kern/sys_setkey.c       standard
```

My sys_setkey.c is as follows

```
#include <sys/sysproto.h>
#include <sys/proc.h>

//required for printf
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/systm.h>

#ifndef _SYS_SYSPROTO_H_
struct setkey_args {
    unsigned int k0;
    unsigned int k1;
};
#endif
/* ARGSUSED */
int sys_setkey(struct thread *td, struct setkey_args *args)
{
    printf("Hello, Kernel!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Also, I added the system call to /kern/capabilities.conf

```
##
## Allow associating SHA1 key with user
##
setkey
```

Finally, while in /usr/src/ I ran the command

```
sudo make -j8 kernel
sudo reboot
```

This is a program which runs the system call

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
//syscall takes syscall.master offset,and the system call arguments
printf("out = %d\n",syscall(546,1,1));
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

I think, that you haven't included your file with `sys_Sum` function in kernel makefile ( notice, that in your code, that you have provided, function name is `Sum` and in error there is call to `sys_Sum`. I hope, that it's just a typo in your code and the name of function is `sys_Sum` ).

Comment: I enter my syscall name in usr/src/sys/conf ---> files... Is it true? If not, where is the make file directory that I should change?

Comment: I'm talking about file with name `Makefile`. If you are not familiar with makefiles, than read some tutorial about it ( for start -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile )