# A simple new system call in FreeBSD-11.0-RELEASE-amd64

Tags: system-calls, freebsd

I am a newbie in FreeBSD. I installed FreeBSD-11.0-RELEASE-amd64 on VMware. I want to add first new system call. I find this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498134/add-new-system-call-at-freebsd-10-1).

I Did:

> cd /usr/src/sys/kern
>
> ee mykern.c

```
#include <sys/sysproto.h>
#include <sys/proc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/systm.h>

#ifndef _SYS_SYSPROTO_H_
struct myargs {
    int k;
};
#endif

int func(struct thread *p, struct myargs *uap)
{
printf("Hello");
return (0);
}
```

I added my system call to the end /kern/syscalls.master

```
550      AUE_NULL      STD { int func(int k);}
```

Then I did

> cd /usr/src
>
> sudo make -C /sys/kern/ sysent

Next, I added the file to /sys/conf/files

```
 kern/mykern.c       standard
```

Also, I added the system call to /kern/capabilities.conf

```
    ##
    ## Allow associating SHA1 key with user
    ##
    func
```

Finally, while in /usr/src/ I ran the command

> sudo make -j8 kernel

And in this step I get:

```
make don't know how to make kernel. Stop

make stopped in /usr/src
```

Comment: It is `make buildkernel`, i suspect.

Comment: make buildkernel , same error! I am losing my hope!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a new system call at FreeBSD-11.0-RELEASE-amd64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186375/add-a-new-system-call-at-freebsd-11-0-release-amd64)

Answer (score 1):

Check that both `Makefile` and `Makefile.inc1` exist in `/usr/src`. The latter is actually where the `buildkernel` target is defined. Verify that that target actually exists in that file.