# Add a new system call at FreeBSD-11.0-RELEASE-amd64

Tags: kernel, system-calls, freebsd

I am a beginner in FreeBSD. I installed FreeBSD-11.0-RELEASE-amd64 on VM.
I want to add first new system call. And this is [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051654/a-simple-new-system-call-in-freebsd-11-0-release-amd64) in last week.
Now I want to build kernel. I see [handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/makeworld.html).
But In command *`make buildkernel`*, indicates errors!

mykern.c

```
#include <sys/sysproto.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/systm.h>
#include <sys/module.h>
#include <sys/kernel.h>
#include <sys/proc.h>
#include <sys/sysent.h>

#ifndef _SYS_SYSPROTO_H_
  struct myargs {
       unsigned int k0;
       unsigned int k1;
};
#endif

int func (struct thread *td, void *args)
{
     struct myargs *uap;
     uap = (struct myargs *)args;
     printf("Hello");
     return (0);
}
```

first error was

```
/usr/src/sys/kern/mykern.c:12:5: error:no previous prototype for function 'func' [-Werror, -Wmissing-prototypes]
int func(struct thread *p, struct myargs *uap)
```

And in mykern.c I edit function to inline:

```
inline int func (struct thread *td, void *args)
```

And now a new error:

```
init sysent.o:(.data 0xg720): undefined refrence to 'sys_func'
```

And when I enter command

```
make init_sysent.c
'init_sysent.c' is up to date
```

Comment: No idea? No experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System calls should have a name starting with `sys_`.
Look at the other files in `/usr/src/sys/kern`.